# Extract first instance of USPS shipping tracking number

Tags: php, regex

How can I extract only the 30 digit TN number once as the end result?

Currently this does the opposite, where the end `$output` is everything except the desired tracking number.

```
$input = "Item/s shipped:
Mug 15oz
TN: 720315589361269903507180163568
URL: https://www.dhl.com/global-en/home/tracking/tracking-ecommerce.html?submit=1&tracking-id=720315589361269903507180163568";
$output = preg_replace('/(?<!\bTN: )\d{30}/', '', $input);
print_r($output);
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/047f7976cfbad5a16fe198f7e8b94ed824afa479

Comment: If you're trying to *extract* a value, why use a function literally named with the word *replace*? Try [`preg_match()`](https://www.php.net/preg_match) instead

Comment: I tried match and the result is `0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code you need with preg_match :

```html
<?php

$input = "Item/s shipped:
Mug 15oz
TN: 720315589361269903507180163568
URL: https://www.dhl.com/global-en/home/tracking/tracking-ecommerce.html?submit=1&tracking-id=720315589361269903507180163568";

preg_match('/TN: (\d{30})/', $input, $output_array);

print_r($output_array[1]);
```